# Capture screenshot from Nexus 10 emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, nexus-10

How do I capture screenshots from the Nexus 10 emulator.  I need these high resolution screenshots to submit to Google Play Store.

I get "Screen not available" when I try using the screen capture tool in the Eclipse tools.  Someone suggested unchecking "Use Host GPU" in the Android Virutal Device Manager but if I do that the emulator will not start.

I think it might be a hardware limitation?  Because Nexus 10 uses very high resolution 2560 x 1600.  I can capture Nexus 7 screenshots fine.

Answer (score 2):

You could try taking the screenshot using adb. First run this to take the screenshot:

```
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screenshot.png
```

Then this to copy it onto your computer:

```
adb pull /sdcard/screenshot.png
```

Edit: I just tried and ran into an issue saying that the emulators file system is read only, so I had to run the following, which did indeed work:

```
adb shell
su
mount -o rw,remount rootfs /
exit
screencap -p /sdcard/screenshot.png
exit
adb pull /sdcard/screenshot.png
```

Comment: does not work, it creates a png with a file size of 0 bytes. maybe it works for you because you check "use host gpu"?

Comment: An alternative would be to use Genymotion to emulate the nexus 10 resolution and take the screenshot from there.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, use the snipping tool to take a screenshot of that part of your screen.